# Conditionally selecting a column (weird results)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In a SQL request I calculate something. This calculus needs a table (`DurationsLog`) not to be empty (the table has to contain rows).

So I'm trying to handle the case where this table is empty.

So I tried to handle it using a CASE in the select but it's not working (got 0 rows when `DurationsLog` is empty).

Here is the request:

```
SELECT 
   o.Maint,
   CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DurationsLog)  
        THEN DATEADD(day, (p.CycleDuration - (c.TotalRotationCounter - o.LastActionCounter)) / AVG(d.RotationDuration), GetDate())  
        ELSE 'CALCUL IMPOSSIBLE'  
   END AS CalculProchaineDate
FROM 
   dbo.Operations o  
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Periods As p ON o.PeriodId = p.Id,
    dbo.Counters c,  
    dbo.DurationsLog d  
WHERE 
   p.CycleDuration>0  
GROUP BY 
   o.Maint, p.CycleDuration, c.TotalRotationCounter, o.LastActionCounter
```

NB: `DurationsLog` has no join with another table

NB bis: When `DurationsLog` contains rows it's working properly

NB 3: the SQL system is Microsoft SQL Server 2008

**Edit**: Seems like I didn't explain well my problem, I'll detail it a bit more:

dbo.Operations table contains information about maintenance operations. Its primary key is "Maint" and it contains a foreign key "PeriodId" on dbo.Periods table.

dbo.Periods table contains an Id as primary key and a field "CycleDuration" which I use for the calculus

dbo.Counters doesn't have primary key. It contains total counters of machine use (how many hours did it rotate, produce...), this table always contains only one row

dbo.DurationsLog contains a primary key which is a date. This table store how much time did our machine rotate and produce today. So this table contains one row / day

The "CycleDuration" from Periods stores how much time (in hours) between two operations (example: we need to clean x every 4000 hours, CycleDuration will be 4000)

We store in Operations table the last time we performed this operation. So I estimate when will the next operation needs to get performed.

That's why I'm calculating: CycleDuration - (Counter Of Last Time I Performed The Operation) / Average duration per day. With that I can estimate when the next operations will take place.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - use the proper ANSI-**92** Standard `INNER JOIN` / `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax (and most definitely **do not mix** the two styles!)

Comment: @marc_s could you be more specific, how would you rewrite joins in this request? As far as I know I'm using an INNER JOIN (Counters & DurationsLog tables have no joins with others tables)

Comment: You're **not** using proper `INNER JOIN` for tables `dbo.Counters c` and `dbo.DurationsLog d` .... if you have "no joins", then use `CROSS JOIN` or a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to be SQL-92 compliant

Comment: I'm not using any JOIN for Counters & DurationsLog, there's no relation between Operations and those tables (those tables are independant)

Comment: @marc_s ok thank you! didn't know that, will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is, when you have `DurationsLog` table empty, INNER JOIN would be always empty
Precisely here:

```
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.Periods As p ON o.PeriodId = p.Id,
        dbo.Counters c,  
        dbo.DurationsLog d
```

you have no connect conditions between tables `Counters`, `DurationsLog` and the rest of the query.

The solution is to precalculate necessary values instead joining the tables themself:

```
declare @AvgDuration float;
select 
  @AvgDuration = AVG( d.RotationDuration )
from dbo.DurationsLog d;

declare @TotalCounter int;
select 
  @TotalCounter = c.TotalRotationCounter
from dbo.Counters;

SELECT 
   o.Maint,
   CASE 
      WHEN @AvgDuration IS NOT NULL
        THEN DATEADD(day, (p.CycleDuration - 
             (@TotalCounter - o.LastActionCounter)) 
              / @AvgDuration, GetDate())  
        ELSE 'CALCUL IMPOSSIBLE'  
   END AS CalculProchaineDate
FROM 
   dbo.Operations o  
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Periods As p ON o.PeriodId = p.Id
WHERE 
   p.CycleDuration>0  
GROUP BY 
   o.Maint, p.CycleDuration, o.LastActionCounter;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this request gives me a syntax error. LEFT JOIN is waiting for a 'ON t1.id = t2.id' or something like. Problem is there's no relationship between Counters and Durations and any other table. What I'm storing is those is counters which I use to calculate a date. DurationsLog contains the hour count of a machine use during this day, everyday a row is added. Counters contains the same thing, except it's storing the total of those counters. Then I try to estimate when the next Operation will be required.

Comment: So I do: (TimeBetweenTwoOperations - CounterOfLastTimeIDidThisOperation) / AverageUsePerDay to know in how many days I need to do again this same Operations (maintenance operation)

Comment: Well, if there are now interdependence between Counters, DurationsLog then why not just precalculate necessary values? I modified my answer due this approach

Comment: Edit: this comment has been written before you edited your post.Couldn't make your code work, I edited my post to give more information about this problem. I may have explain it badly.

Comment: Glad to be helpful, mate :)